# What's the purpose of the END field in files containing metadata for ffmpeg?

Tags: video, ffmpeg

## Table of contents

- The context
- Minimal working example

  - no. 1
  - no. 2
  - no. 3
- The questions

## The context

I'm aware that it is possible to insert metadata of chapters into a video using ffmpeg [(link to documentation)](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#Metadata-1). Minimal working example no. 1 shows this point.

When I insert chapters that are not consecutive, ffmpeg doesn't use the end time that is specified in the metadata file through the `END` field. "Minimal working example no. 2" shows this point. In "Minimal working example no. 3", the `END` field of all chapters is 1 millisecond, yet we get the same result of Minimal working example no. 2. What is worth noting is that the `END` of the last chapter is the only one that is added correctly.

## Minimal working example

### no. 1

Consider the following ffmpeg metadata file. It creates chapters in the following time ranges

- From `0` to millisecond `9999`, the chapter is `This is my chapter one`
- From `10000` to millisecond `19999`, the chapter is `This is my chapter two`
- From `20000` to millisecond `29999`, the chapter is `This is my chapter three`
- From `30000` to millisecond `39999`, the chapter is `This is my chapter four`

```
;FFMETADATA1
title=The title of my video

[CHAPTER]
TIMEBASE=1/1000
START=0
END=10000
title=This is my chapter one

[CHAPTER]
TIMEBASE=1/1000
START=10000
END=20000
title=This is my chapter two

[CHAPTER]
TIMEBASE=1/1000
START=20000
END=30000
title=This is my chapter three
```

The following command creates a simple video and inserts the metadata shown above into that video.

```bash
ffmpeg -v error -y -f lavfi -i 'testsrc=d=120:size=100x100' -i metadata.txt -map_metadata 1 output.mp4
```

The following command shows information about the metadata in the video file that was created by the previous command.

```bash
ffprobe -v error -show_chapters -print_format json output.mp4 | jq
```

```
{
  "chapters": [
    {
      "id": 0,
      "time_base": "1/1000",
      "start": 0,
      "start_time": "0.000000",
      "end": 10000,
      "end_time": "10.000000",
      "tags": {
        "title": "This is my chapter one"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": 1,
      "time_base": "1/1000",
      "start": 10000,
      "start_time": "10.000000",
      "end": 20000,
      "end_time": "20.000000",
      "tags": {
        "title": "This is my chapter two"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "time_base": "1/1000",
      "start": 20000,
      "start_time": "20.000000",
      "end": 30000,
      "end_time": "30.000000",
      "tags": {
        "title": "This is my chapter three"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

No problem until here.

### no. 2

```
;FFMETADATA1
title=The title of my video

[CHAPTER]
TIMEBASE=1/1000
START=0
END=5000
title=This is my chapter one

[CHAPTER]
TIMEBASE=1/1000
START=10000
END=15000
title=This is my chapter two

[CHAPTER]
TIMEBASE=1/1000
START=20000
END=25000
title=This is my chapter three
```

The following command creates a simple video and inserts the metadata shown above into that video.

```bash
ffmpeg -v error -y -f lavfi -i 'testsrc=d=120:size=100x100' -i metadata.txt -map_metadata 1 output.mp4
```

The following command shows information about the metadata in the video file that was created by the previous command.

```bash
ffprobe -v error -show_chapters -print_format json output.mp4 | jq
```

```
{
  "chapters": [
    {
      "id": 0,
      "time_base": "1/1000",
      "start": 0,
      "start_time": "0.000000",
      "end": 10000,
      "end_time": "10.000000",
      "tags": {
        "title": "This is my chapter one"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": 1,
      "time_base": "1/1000",
      "start": 10000,
      "start_time": "10.000000",
      "end": 20000,
      "end_time": "20.000000",
      "tags": {
        "title": "This is my chapter two"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "time_base": "1/1000",
      "start": 20000,
      "start_time": "20.000000",
      "end": 25000,
      "end_time": "25.000000",
      "tags": {
        "title": "This is my chapter three"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

From the output above, we can notice the following:

- The end time of the chapter with title `This is my chapter one` is 10000 which should be 15000, since that is the value we specified in the `END` field
- The end time of the chapter with title `This is my chapter two` is 20000 which should be 25000, since that is the value we specified in the `END` field
- The end time of the last chapter is the only one that is the same to the value that we wrote in the metadata file

I consider this unexpected behavior because ffmpeg should use the end time that we have specified in the metadata file.

### no. 3

```
;FFMETADATA1
title=The title of my video

[CHAPTER]
TIMEBASE=1/1000
START=0
END=1
title=This is my chapter one

[CHAPTER]
TIMEBASE=1/1000
START=10000
END=10001
title=This is my chapter two

[CHAPTER]
TIMEBASE=1/1000
START=20000
END=20001
title=This is my chapter three
```

The following command creates a simple video and inserts the metadata shown above into that video.

```bash
ffmpeg -v error -y -f lavfi -i 'testsrc=d=120:size=100x100' -i metadata.txt -map_metadata 1 output.mp4
```

The following command shows information about the metadata in the video file that was created by the previous command.

```bash
ffprobe -v error -show_chapters -print_format json output.mp4 | jq
```

```
{
  "chapters": [
    {
      "id": 0,
      "time_base": "1/1000",
      "start": 0,
      "start_time": "0.000000",
      "end": 10000,
      "end_time": "10.000000",
      "tags": {
        "title": "This is my chapter one"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": 1,
      "time_base": "1/1000",
      "start": 10000,
      "start_time": "10.000000",
      "end": 20000,
      "end_time": "20.000000",
      "tags": {
        "title": "This is my chapter two"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "time_base": "1/1000",
      "start": 20000,
      "start_time": "20.000000",
      "end": 20001,
      "end_time": "20.001000",
      "tags": {
        "title": "This is my chapter three"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

From the output above, we can notice the following:

- The end time of the chapter with title `This is my chapter one` is `10000`, but it should be `15000`, since that is the value we specified in the `END` field in the metadata file
- The end time of the chapter with title `This is my chapter two` is `20000`, but it should be `25000`, since that is the value we specified in the `END` field in the metadata file
- The end time of the last chapter is the only one that is the same to the value that we wrote in the metadata file

I consider this unexpected behavior because ffmpeg should use the end time that we have specified in the metadata file.

## The questions

In minimal working example no. 2 and minimal working example no. 3, we could see that although the metadata file sets `END` for each chapter, a different time is used (except for the last chapter). My questions are:

- What's the purpose of having a field called `END` when it only serves a purpose in the last chapter?
- Given that `ffmpeg` only adds the correct value for `END` for the last chapter? Wouldn't a better name for `END` be `END_ONLY_FOR_LAST_CHAPTER`?
- Am I doing something wrong that is casuing ffmpeg to use a different value for `END` in all chapters but the last one?

Comment: I just found this question that is related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74863387

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because , as the ffmpeg tag states: Only questions about programmatic use of the FFmpeg libraries, API, or tools are on topic. Questions about interactive use of the command line tool should be asked on https://superuser.com/ or https://video.stackexchange.com/. Please delete this.